# Python file runs successfully in Terminal,but gives error when double-clicking it

Tags: python, popen

I want to run IntelliJ IDEA by this code :

```
os.popen('cd /opt/idea-IU-141.1532.4/bin && ./idea.sh')
```

when I run it in Terminal , it works : IDEA runs successfully .
but when double clicking Python file , *idea.sh*  runs but gives errors:

```
No JDK found. Please validate either IDEA_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation.
```

Why ?

Comment: are you on OSX? Compare `os.environ` in both cases.

Comment: Calling it from terminal inherits the terminal environment variables, which include `JDK_HOME`. Double clicking it doesn't inherit any variable (unless the launcher manually specifys them). Which OS are you using? In linux it can be solve by adding `env JDK_HOME=/your/java/home ./yourscript` to an .sh executable file (or to `exec=` property in a launcher).

Comment: Following on from J.F. Sebastian's comment, could you also do this by setting `os.environ["JDK_HOME"]` prior to the `popen` call?

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 .I do as  imaluengo told and it works !  Thank you very much !  Thank you all !